# bash cant compare strings with or statement

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
ENVIRONMENT=production
if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" != "production" -o  "$ENVIRONMENT" != "staging" ]; then
   echo "$ENVIRONMENT is not supported, you may use production or staging"
   exit
fi
```

this is the output:
`$ production is not supported, you may use production or staging`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: After `ENVIRONMENT=production`, the condition of the if statement is false for the first test and true for the second test. Since "false or true" is "true", the if statement is executed. See solution of choroba below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `-a` instead of `-o`. If $ENVIRONMENT is `production`, it still isn't `staging`.

Comment: `-o` is "or", `-a` is "and". Any string is always not "production" or not "staging", as no string can be both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` instead it's more convenient

```
ENVIRONMENT=production

case "$ENVIRONMENT" in
    production|staging) : ;; # : means do nothing
    *                 ) echo "$ENVIRONMENT is not supported, you may use production or staging";;
esac
```